# Generating all combinations with repetition using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinations, combinatorics, multiset

How do I create all [*k-combinations with repetitions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) of a given set (also called *k-multicombinations* or *multisubsets*) using MATLAB?

This is similar to the cartesian product, but two rows that only differ by their sorting should be considered the same (e.g. the vectors `[1,1,2]=~=[1,2,1]` are considered to be the same), so generating the cartesian product and then applying `unique(sort(cartesianProduct,2),'rows')` should yield the same results.

**Example:**
The call `nmultichoosek(1:n,k)` should generate the following matrix:

```
nmultichoosek(1:3,3)
ans =
     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     3     3
     2     2     2
     2     2     3
     2     3     3
     3     3     3
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use the bijection mentioned in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition), which maps combinations without repetition of type `n+k-1 choose k` to `k`-multicombinations of size `n`. We generate the combinations without repetition and map them using `bsxfun(@minus, nchoosek(1:n+k-1,k), 0:k-1);`. This results in the following function:

```
function combs = nmultichoosek(values, k)
%// Return number of multisubsets or actual multisubsets.
if numel(values)==1 
    n = values;
    combs = nchoosek(n+k-1,k);
else
    n = numel(values);
    combs = bsxfun(@minus, nchoosek(1:n+k-1,k), 0:k-1);
    combs = reshape(values(combs),[],k);
end
```

Comment: Ver fast and memory-efficient! Great question and answer

Comment: Do you really need that `reshape`? Isn't `combs = values(combs);` enough?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I just did it, so for `k=1` it will return a column vector. Otherwise it could be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

*Thanks to [Hans Hirse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11089932/hanshirse) for a correction*.

Brute-force approach: generate all tuples and then keep only those that are sorted. Not suitable for large values of `n` or `k`.

```
values = 1:3;                               %//  data
k = 3;                                      %//  data
n = numel(values);                          %//  number of values
combs = values(dec2base(0:n^k-1,n)-'0'+1);  %//  generate all tuples
combs = combs(all(diff(combs.')>=0, 1),:);  %'// keep only those that are sorted
```

Comment: May I suggest the following change: `combs = combs(all(diff(combs.')>=0, 1),:);` For `k = 2`, the result of the `diff` is a `1 x m` vector, such that `all` works along the second axis, but what you want is `all` (explicitly) working along the first axis, so setting the `dim` parameter to `1` now enables this solution to also work for `k = 2`. :-)

Comment: @HansHirse You are totally right. Updated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an even more brutal (memory intensive) method than previous posts, but a tidy readable one-liner:

```
 combs = unique(sort(nchoosek(repmat(values,1,k),k),2),'rows');
```