# How to generate all the possible combinations of three variables that sum to 1

Tags: python

I need to solve the equation x + y + z = 1.

I need to generate all the possible combinations of x, y, z so the equation is correct

I want the values of x, y, z to be between 0.1 and 0.9 with jump of 0.1.

So the values are restricted to [0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.8, 0.9]

I have found this answer [Finding all combinations of multiple variables summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507040/finding-all-combinations-of-multiple-variables-summing-to-1)

However it applies to R not python.

It would be very helpfull if someone would enlighten me.

Comment: `I need to generate all the possible combinations of x, y, z so the equation is correct.` What is the domain for `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: It is the plane x+y+z=1 in 3 D space. It is the unique plane through (0,0,1), (0,1,0) and (1,0,0).

Comment: You can not generate all values, as there are uncountable many of them.

Comment: Without more constraints, there is an infinity of solutions. Please update your question to indicate which ones you are looking for.

Comment: I have added the restrictions. I want the values to be between 0.1 and 0.9 with jumps of 0.1.

Comment: *'steps of 0.1'* or *'increments of 0.1'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a nested triple loop, you can consider generating all triplets

```
triplets = [(x/10.0, y/10.0, (10-x-y)/10.0) for x in range(1,9) for y in range(1,10-x)]
```

where each triplet `(a,b,c)` represents the possible values to be assigned to `x, y`, and `z`.

Note that I'm multiplying by 10 for then dividing when building the triplets to avoid rounding errors that might come up when doing directly:

```
if x/10 + y/10 + z/10 == 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

The most primitive solution would be a nested loop over all combinations:

```
def variable_combinations(sum_up_to=1):
    for x in range(1, 10):
        for y in range(1, 10):
            for z in range(1, 10):
                if x/10 + y/10 + z/10 == sum_up_to:
                    yield (x/10, y/10, z/10)

all_solutions = list(variable_combinations())
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding nested loops directly in python:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
x = y = z = [ i/10 for i in range(1,10)]

p = itertools.product(x,y,z)
combs = [e for e in p if np.sum(e) == 1]
```

Now `combs` is a list of triplets (tuples) that sum to 1.