# how do I combine only the vectors - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

How do I combine  all the vectors in small subsets of vectors  in Matlab?

```
a= [5 6 7] b = [8 9 10] c=[11 12 13] d=[14 15 16] e=[17 18 19]
```

a combine with b and c:

Outcome:

```
M1= [ 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]
```

a with b and d:

```
M2 = [5 6 7 8 9 10 14 15 16]
```

and so on .....

Comment: So, combine in groups of 3 without repetitions? Are all those vectors  of lengths 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer covers the case for an **arbitrary number of vectors**. The vectors are assumed to be row vectors of equal length.

Let your example data be defined as

```
a = [5 6 7]; b = [8 9 10]; c = [11 12 13]; d = [14 15 16]; e = [17 18 19];
vectors = {a, b, c, d, e}; %// cell array with any number of row vectors of equal size
n = 3; %// desired subset size
```

Then: generate all combinations of indices, use that to index into `vectors`, concatenate into one big row vector, and reshape that to obtain the desired result:

```
combs = nchoosek(1:numel(vectors), n);
result = reshape([vectors{combs.'}], numel(vectors{1})*n, []).';
```

This gives a matrix whose first row is your `M1`, second row is `M2` etc:

```
result =
     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
     5     6     7     8     9    10    14    15    16
     5     6     7     8     9    10    17    18    19
     5     6     7    11    12    13    14    15    16
     5     6     7    11    12    13    17    18    19
     5     6     7    14    15    16    17    18    19
     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
     8     9    10    11    12    13    17    18    19
     8     9    10    14    15    16    17    18    19
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
```

Comment: Yes, as stated in my code. The OP example seems to suggest that. But the question is not clear

Comment: You don't need to deal with cell arrays then I guess: `A = cat(1,a,b,c,d,e).'; out = reshape(A(:,nchoosek(1:5,3).'),9,[]).';`? Very similar to your existing one.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, for the 5-vector case I agree. I tried to make it more general so that it works for any number of vectors. I'll make that clearer in my answer

Comment: Luis Mendo's answer is what I was looking for. A general approach for same size vectors. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cat` function:

```
res = cat(2,a,b,c);
```

or simply the `[]` syntax:

```
res = [a b c];
```

In both cases, `res` will contain `[5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]`.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Use `nchoosek`.

```
a = [5 6 7]; b = [8 9]; c = [11 12 13]; d = [14 15 16]; e = [17 18 19];
N = 3;
x = {a,b,c,d,e};
y = nchoosek(x,N);
```

And you have all the combination of your arrays taken `N` at a time in a cell array. Each row `i` of the cell `x` is a combination, so to have it back as a row vector just do

```
horzcat(y{i,:})
```

Or, if you want to get them all and put them in a cell array of size `n_combs`

```
n_combs = size(y,1);
out = cell(0,n_combs);
for i = 1 : n_combs
    out{i} = horzcat(1, y{i,:});
end
```

There is no constraint on the size of the arrays that you want to combine, e.g., you can combine

```
a = [5 7]; b = [8 9]; c = [11]; d = [20 14 15 16]; e = [17 18 19];
```

However, if you must put together all the combination in a matrix, then the arrays have to be of the same size. In this case Luis Mendo's answer does the job.

Finally, if repetitions are allowed use [nmultichoosek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284671/generating-all-combinations-with-repetition-using-matlab) instead of `nchoosek`.