# Choose multiple combination (matlab)

Tags: matlab, combinations

I have 3 sets of array each contains 12 elements of same type

```
a=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
b=[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2];
c=[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3];
```

I have to find how many ways it can be picked up if I need to pickup 12 items at a time

```
here, 1 1 2 is same as 2 1 1
```

I found this link [Generating all combinations with repetition using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284671/generating-all-combinations-with-repetition-using-matlab).

Ho this can be done in matlab within reasonable time.

is that way correct

```
abc=[a b c];
allcombs=nmultichoosek(abc,12);
combs=unique(allcombs,'rows');
```

Comment: Does the linked solution not work for you?  It appears to be doing exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: For finding 12 solutions at a time taking indefinite time any wau out so that it could be done in reasonable time? what I am doing
abc=[a b c];
allcombs=nmultichoosek(abc,12);
combs=unique(allcombs,'rows');

is that way?

Comment: Yes, finding all combinations will be computationally very very slow, if thats what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to find the number of ways to select the items, then using generating functions is a way to very efficiently compute that, even for fairly large values of N and k.

If you are not familiar with generating functions, you can read up on the math background here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html

and here:

http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/combinatoricsweb/generate.pdf

The solution hinges on the fact that the number of ways to choose `k` items from 36, with each of 3 items repeated 12 times, can be determined from the product of the generating function:

```
g(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^12
```

with itself 3 times.  The `12` comes from the fact the elements are repeated 12 times (NOT from the fact you are choosing 12), and multiplying by itself 3 times is because there are three different sets of elements.  The number of ways to choose 12 elements is then just the coefficient of the power of x^12 in this product of polynomials (try it for smaller examples if you want to prove to yourself that it works).

The great thing about that is that MATLAB has a simple function `conv` for multiplying polynomials:

```
>> g = ones(1,13);  %% array of 13 ones, for a 12th degree polynomial with all `1` coefficents
>> prod = conv(g, conv(g, g));  %% multiply g by itself 3 times, as a polynomial
>> prod(13)
ans = 
     91
```

So there are 91 ways to select 12 elements from your list of 36.  If you want to select 11 elements, that's `z(12)` = 78.  If you want to select 13 elements, that's `z(14)` = 102.

Finally, if you had different numbers of elements in the sets, say 10 `1`'s, 12 `2`'s, and 14 `3`'s, then you would have 3 distinct polynomials of the same form, `1 + x + x^2 + ...`, with degrees 10, 12 and 14 respectively.  Inspecting the coefficient of the degree `k` term again gives you the number of ways to choose `k` elements from this set.