# Generating a Matrix from a given vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Im trying to generate a specific type o matrix in Matlab.

I need to modify it for specific types of data with the following rules:

- First I have to choose a grade `g` (max 6 let's say) then I have to choose the number of elements per row `n` (max 18) ;
- These numbers are the powers of a specific polynomial of grade `g` ;
- The sum per row in the matrix is not allowed to be bigger than the chosen `g` grade ;
- The biggest element per row is the chosen `g`.

For `g = 2`, `n = 2` the matrix will look like this:

```
A = [0 0; 
     0 1; 
     1 0; 
     0 2; 
     2 0; 
     1 1]
```

For `g = 2`, `n = 3` the matrix will look like this:

```
A = [0 0 0; 
     0 0 1; 
     0 0 2; 
     0 1 0; 
     0 2 0; 
     1 0 0; 
     2 0 0; 
     0 1 1; 
     1 0 1;
     1 1 0]
```

How can I generate all possible combinations of an array elements?

```
Ex : given v = [0 1 2];

Result = [0 0 0;
          0 0 1;
          0 1 0;
          0 1 1;
          1 0 0;
          1 0 1;
          1 1 0;
          1 1 1;
          0 0 2;
          0 2 0;
          2 0 0;
          2 0 1;
          2 1 1;
          2 1 2;
            ...]
and so on...
```

I've tried this with `perms`, `nchoosek`, `repelem`, `repmat`, `for-loops`, `unique`, `matrix concatenations`, everything but I couldn't be able to find and algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first generate all `n` permutations of `[0..g]` with repetition and rearrangement, then select allowed combinations:

```
% all n permutations of [0..g] (with repetition and rearrangement)
powers = unique(nchoosek(repmat(0:g, 1, n), n), 'row');
% allowed set of powers
powers = powers(sum(powers, 2) <= g, :);
```

As I already said in comments, the above code is extremely time and memory inefficient. For example when I run it for `g=6` and `n=9`, MATLAB gives the following error:

> Error using zeros Requested 23667689815x9 (1587.0GB) array exceeds
> maximum array size preference.
> ...

To reduce memory consumption, you can do the following:

```matlab
% all n permutations of [0..g] (with repetition)
gPerms = nmultichoosek(0:g, n);
% allowed set of powers
allowed = gPerms(sum(gPerms, 2) <= g, :);
% all permutations of [1..n] (no repetition)
nPerms = perms(1:n);
% all n permutations of [0..g] (with repetition and rearrangement)
arranges = arrayfun(@(i) allowed(:, nPerms(i, :)), ...
    1:size(nPerms, 1), 'UniformOutput', false)';
powers = cell2mat(arranges);
% unique set of permutations
powers = unique(powers, 'rows');
```

In the above code, first `n` permutations with repetition of `g` is generated using [@knedlsepp's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284672/2093077). The filtered to keep only combinations that their sums is less than or equal to `g`. In next step all rearrangements of these combinations are calculated. It still takes more than 13 seconds here to find `5005` combinations for the `g=6` and `n=9` case.

Comment: that is perfect.thank you so much i ve tried this all day with no succes. 200+ lines of code transformed in 2 . thanks a lot

Comment: @netseg I'm glad it helped. Note that this is very time and memory consuming. In a way that you can not even get close to the `g=6` and `n=18`. I'm afraid you will have to return all those 200 lines back for such values.

Comment: @netseg updated my answer for a more memory efficient implementation.

Comment: thank you this is even better.for my needs i think that  the first one is enough.anyway for my bigger projects ill use the second one.thank you again